# Different header for odd and even pages with elsarticle class

Tags: header, latex

I'm writting an article in Latex with the document class **elsarticle**. I've tried the fancyhdr package to customize the headings for odd and even pages. I've also rewritted the class "@pprintTitle" to obtain such a headers. None of the methods worked. I tested the fancyhdr with the document class "article" and "book" and it works perfectly. But I need to use the document class **elsarticle**, for which fancyhdr does not work. The example that I'm trying to modify is the following one:

https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/example-of-elsevier-article-template-with-dummy-text/qfscmwntknmq

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]?

Comment: [**This answer**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152454/49683) contains useful info, maybe related